# Count Correct Answers with Button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to count the correct answers in a quiz so that when the player clicks on the correct answer, the counter will add one, and at the end of the quiz, the html will say "you got" + correct + " answers correct".

**Desired outcome:**
Displays the amount of answers the player answered correctly.

As you can see I have already tried some things, but the are not working.

```js
var index = 0;

function nextButton() {
  document.getElementById("questionHere").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].iq;
  document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia1;
  document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia2;
  document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia3;
  if (index < iconquiz.length) {
    index++
  }
}

function prevButton() {
  document.getElementById("questionHere").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].iq;
  document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia1;
  document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia2;
  document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia3;
  if (index != 0) {
    index--
  }
}

var counter = 0;

function buttonClicked(number) {
  if (iconquiz[index].correct === number) {
    counter++
  }
}

var iconquiz = [{
    iq: "Please Begin",
    ia1: "This is a quiz over different icons used in the coding community!",
    ia2: "",
    ia3: ""
  },

  {
    iq: "which icon is used for GitHub?",
    ia1: "<i class='fa fa-gitlab fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='incorrect'>",
    ia2: "<i class='fa fa-grav fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='incorrect'>",
    ia3: "<i class='fa fa-github-alt fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='correct'>"
    correct: 3
  },

  {
    iq: "What is this? " + "<i class='fa fa-gitlab' aria-hidden='true'></i>",
    ia1: "GitHub" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='incorrect'>",
    ia2: "Atom.io" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='incorrect'>",
    ia3: "GitLab" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='correct'>"
  },
  {
    iq: "question number three",
    ia1: "1 ",
    ia2: "2 ",
    ia3: "3 "
  },

  {
    iq: "no more!",
    ia1: "you got " + correct + " answers correct!",
    ia2: "",
    ia3: ""

  },



];
```

```css
/*************
MAIN STUFFF
*************/

body {
  background: #CCC;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.collapse {
  color: #fff;
  background: #494949;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#correct:active {
  color: #4ada95;
}

#correct:focus {
  color: #4ada95;
}


/*************
QUIZ BOXES
*************/

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.answers {
  display: inline;
  visibility: visible;
}

label {
  width: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4ada95;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label:hover {
  color: #494949;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label::before {}


/************
QUIZ CONTENT
************/

h3 {
  background-color: #707070;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #707070;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #707070;
  margin: 5px;
}

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 73px;
}


/***********
QUIZES
***********/

#expand {
  height: 225px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  background-color: #4ada95;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}


/**********
FIRST QUIZ
**********/

#toggle:checked~#expand {
  height: 0px;
}

#toggle:checked~label::before {
  display: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="quiz.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <div class="collapse">
      <h2>Icon Quiz</h2>
      <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
      <label for="toggle">take quiz</label>
      <div id="expand">
        <section>
          <h3 id="questionHere">Please Begin</h3>
          <section>
            <li id="answer1" onclick="buttonClicked(1)">This is a quiz over different icons used in the coding community!</li>
            <li id="answer2" onclick="buttonClicked(2)"></li>
            <li id="answer3" onclick="buttonClicked(3)"></li>
          </section>
        </section>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button onclick="prevButton()" type="button">prev</button><button onclick="nextButton()" type="button">next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the idea itself is not good : a click event could not tell you about the correct number of the clicked right  answers since a user can click a correct answer x times, you have to use radio inputs.

Comment: @Amani okay, so I've got radios now, but how do I make them count?

Comment: can u update your code then?

Comment: @Amani okay, done

Comment: Try to apply object oriented paradigm here, would be a better choice.

Comment: I posted a proposition but it can be done on a better  way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a proposition sure you can find a better solution:

I used this data structure:

```
var iconquiz =[
{"question" : "Question 1" ,"answers" : ["Answer 1.1","Answer 1.2","Answer 1.3"] ,"correct" :2 ,"was_correct":0},
{"question" : "Question 2" ,"answers" : ["Answer 2.1","Answer 2.2","Answer 2.3"] ,"correct" :3,"was_correct":0},
{"question" : "Question 3" ,"answers" : ["Answer 3.1","Answer 3.2","Answer 3.3"] ,"correct" :3,"was_correct":0}
];
```

List of questions with related answers and correct answer index (if you indicate the correct answer in your html by giving it `correct` class the user can cheat).

I used the `was_correct` property to increment the score by correct answer (or decremented the score by wrong answer) just once pro question.

2- make sure that increment/decrements your index in the correct interval

```
function nextButton() {
   if(index < iconquiz.length-1 ){
      index++;
   }
}


function prevButton() {
   if(index > 0){
      index--;
   }
}
```

3- you can calculate the score one time after clicking a submit button or on each time the user make a change.

```
var radios = document.getElementsByClassName("answers");
for(radio in radios) {
   radios[radio].onchange = function() {
      if(iconquiz[this.dataset.question].was_correct==0){
        if(iconquiz[this.dataset.question].correct == this.value)   {
          correct ++;iconquiz[this.dataset.question].was_correct=1;
        }
      }
   else if(iconquiz[this.dataset.question].correct != this.value){
      correct --;iconquiz[this.dataset.question].was_correct=0;
   } 
 }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/oou8fxn5/)

Comment: thanks! how do I make it print inside the answers div rather than have an alert?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure to prevent user from clicking previous first because you index will be lower than 0 and it will throw you an error for trying to access the array with minus index. Simple if statement in prevButton() function should do the trick

```
if (index != 0) {
    index--;
    code...
}
```

and do the same in nextButton() function index shouldn't be greater than iconquiz.length

```
if (index < iconquiz.length-1) {
    index++;
    code...
}
```

About counter issue, add to your array new field which will indicate which answer is correct, for example

```
{
    iq: "which icon is used for GitHub?",
    ia1: "<i class='fa fa-gitlab fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "<button type='submit' value='submit'><i class='fa fa-heart-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>",
    ia2: "<i class='fa fa-grav fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "<button type='submit' value='submit'><i class='fa fa-heart-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>",
    ia3: "<i class='fa fa-github-alt fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'>" + "</i><button type='submit' value='submit' id='correct'><i class='fa fa-heart-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>",
    correct: 3
  }
```

then add another function where you check the clicked buttons with current array element and its correct id answer.

```
function buttonClicked(number) {
    if (iconquiz[index].correct === number) {
        counter++
    }
}
```

and every button should be assigned with onclick function

```
<li onclick="buttonClicked(1)" id="answer1"></li>
<li onclick="buttonClicked(2)" id="answer2"></li>
<li onclick="buttonClicked(3)" id="answer3"></li>
```

Catch i think you should be able to work with it for your own

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        var index = 0;
        var counter = 0;
        var iconquiz = [
            {
                iq: "Please Begin",
                ia1: "This is a quiz over different icons used in the coding community!",
                ia2: "",
                ia3: ""
            },
            {
                iq: "which icon is used for GitHub?",
                ia1: "<i class='fa fa-gitlab fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='incorrect'>",
                ia2: "<i class='fa fa-grav fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='incorrect'>",
                ia3: "<i class='fa fa-github-alt fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i>" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='correct'>",
                correct: 3
            },
            {
                iq: "What is this? " + "<i class='fa fa-gitlab' aria-hidden='true'></i>",
                ia1: "GitHub" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='incorrect'>",
                ia2: "Atom.io" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='incorrect'>",
                ia3: "GitLab" + "<input class='answers' type='radio' name='answer' value='correct'>",
                correct: 3
            },
            {
                iq: "question number three",
                ia1: "1 ",
                ia2: "2 ",
                ia3: "3 "
            },
        ];
        function buttonClicked(number) {
            if (iconquiz[index].correct === number) {
                counter++
            }
        }
        function nextButton() {
            if (index < iconquiz.length-1) {
                index++;
                document.getElementById("questionHere").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].iq;
                document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia1;
                document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia2;
                document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia3;
            }
            if (iconquiz.length-1 === index) {
                document.getElementById("questionHere").innerHTML = 'you got ' + counter + ' answers correct!'
            }
        }

        function prevButton() {
            if (index != 0) {
                index--;
                document.getElementById("questionHere").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].iq;
                document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia1;
                document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia2;
                document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = iconquiz[index].ia3;
            }
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Icon Quiz</h2>
    <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label for="toggle">take quiz</label>
    <div id="expand">
        <section>
            <h3 id="questionHere">Please Begin</h3>
            <section>
                <li onclick="buttonClicked(1)" id="answer1"></li>
                <li onclick="buttonClicked(2)" id="answer2"></li>
                <li onclick="buttonClicked(3)" id="answer3"></li>
            </section>
        </section>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button onclick="prevButton()" type="button">prev</button><button onclick="nextButton()" type="button">next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working for me, now I can't click next or prev

Comment: it says that "correct: 3" is an unexpected identifier

Comment: make sure to add --> ; for example 
index--;
index++;
counter++;

Comment: "correct: 3" is an unexpected identifier <-- you get this error because you have to add --> , in previous field before the correct: 3